# Python - суммирование внутри списка с заданным шагом

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Озадачила следующая ситуация.
Есть некий список mList длиной 60 значений, которые мне нужно просуммировать с шагом 20.
скрипт ниже, дает неверные значения

```
import numpy as np
res=[]
for i in range(0,len(mList),20):
    r=np.sum(mList[i:i+20])
    res.append(r)
print(res)
```

Но верные ответы получаются если складывать "по индексу" в таком виде

```
np.sum(mList[0:20])
np.sum(mList[21:40])
np.sum(mList[41:60])
```

Озадачило в том числе то, что в тестовом списке результаты получились верные.

```
import numpy as np
mList=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]

res=[]
for i in range(0,len(mList),3):
    r=np.sum(mList[i:i+3])
    res.append(r)
print(res)
```

Прошу подсказать как можно получить правильные ответы через for?
Фактический список будет содержать несколько тысяч значений...

Comment: прогнали бы через отладчик. Например, `r=np.sum(mList[i:i+20])` в каждом из трех случаев совпадает с `np.sum(mList[0:20])` и т.д.? Если нет - в чем отличие?

Comment: Сергей, до отладчика я еще не дорос )

Comment: 1) Дорастайте прямо сейчас. Это очень просто и выиграет вам массу времени + разовьет профессионально. Ставьте PyCharm Community Edition (он бесплатный), копируйте код в окно основное. Shift+F10 - запуск кода в обычном режиме,  Shift+F9 - запуск кода в режиме отладки. Мышью до запуска накликайте слева на строчками с точками остановки (я тупо на каждой кликаю) и жмите F8 для пошагового прохода. В окне дебаггера увидите все значения. 2) Или без отладчика в вашем коде после строки с `r=` поставьте строку `print ('i:', i, 'r:', r)`  и сравните, что получилось.

Comment: Сергей, pycharm почему-то у меня не работает. А в спайдере как это делать?

Comment: Не знаю. Вряд ли сложно. На форуме каком-нибудь спросите, или видео найдите. Не работал с ним, я в Python 2 месяца. А пока используйте вариант 2 с `print`, он для проблемы такого уровня достаточен.

Comment: Что-то странное у вас. `numpy` у меня не стоит, но без него вычисляется все правильно в цикле `for`. Пример моего кода в ответе (это не ответ! просто тут код не написать). Проверьте, что вы один и тот же тестовый список используете в обоих случаях.

Comment: для отладки юзайте юпитер, гораздо наглядней получается и не нужно весь код каждый раз прогонять

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо. А там- СPython или что-то другое с шансами получить различие в версиях? (как, например, узнал с удивлением, что `x += 1` не все компиляторы-интерпретаторы Python поддержат).

Comment: @leonardik, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ (не мой, к сожалению:-)) полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код автора без `numpy` и с тестовым списком и моими комментами ниже. Код работает правильно. Правильно он будет и с `numpy` работать, как ясно из ответа @CrazyElf, кто нашёл причину. Менять в самом коде ничего не надо.

```
res=[]
# Создлание тестового списка со значениями от 1 до 60 по порядку.
mList = [i for i in range(1,61)]
for i in range(0,len(mList),20):
    r=sum(mList[i:i+20])
    res.append(r)
# Печатает верно суммы: [210, 610, 1010]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы не совсем правильно понимаете про срезы.

```py
np.sum(mList[0:20])
np.sum(mList[21:40])
np.sum(mList[41:60])
```

Этот код должен давать **не правильные** ответы! Потому что правый край среза **не включительный**. Т.е.:

```
mList[0:20]  --> элементы с  0 по 19 (20 элементов)
mList[21:40] --> элементы с 21 по 39 (19 элементов)
mList[41:60] --> элементы с 41 по 59 (19 элементов)
```

Таким образом элементы `20` и `40` у вас пропали из суммирования! А вот в коде, который с циклом, у вас всё правильно написано и всё должно правильно суммироваться. Так что вы просто не с тем сравниваете ответ.

Comment: Да, вот и причина. Правильно: `mList[20:40]` и `mList[40:60]`. А я не посмотрел на эти тестовые срезы, просто предложил тестовый список проверить:-(

Comment: @Сергей Возможно, это описка и дело не в этом, но возможно, что всё же и в этом. Посмотрим )

Answer (score 1):

Причина неверного срабатывания кода в for оказалась простой.
Из-за какого-то бага (?) Питон добавлял в список большое отрицательное число (которого в принципе не могло быть из-за логики расчета), поэтому результаты были неправильные.
Неверное число удаляается в при помощи Del, и все работает нормально.
А вот откуда взялся баг - опять вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
mList=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
a=0
for i in mList:
    if i%20==0:
        a+=mList[i]
```

Comment: Арсен, "Фактический список будет содержать несколько тысяч значений..." И с какой скоростью список такой код обработает против скорости оптимизированного пакета `numpy`? Это же практическая задача, а не учебный пример.